# validateForm required text

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I validate a specific string of text for input "promo"?

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{

var x=document.forms["myInquiry"]["promo"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Please Enter Promo Code");
return false;
}

}

</script>
```

Here's the form. Only relevant code.

```
<form action="contactdummy.php" name="myInquiry" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="promo" type="text"  id="promo" size="17" tabindex=4 />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you facing any problem after append the input tag, because your validation is working at my side.

Answer (score 0):

use `input` tag for submit the form inside the `form` element

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Updated, but you misunderstood my question. I need to require the promo input to read a certain string of text, for example, it must be required for them to enter a code like, "SWEETDEAL".

Comment: you mean, as user type the text into the input `promo`, the validation code is executed for check specific string pattern?

Comment: Sorry, not REQUIRED but, if user types "SWEETDEAL", validateForm is executed to check for that string pattern, "SWEETDEAL'. Sorry, hope that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, but what would be your string pattern to be matched with user's input?, I mean if user types 'SWEETDEAL' what pattern should be match with it eg:-, exact same word, case-sensitive or something else?